# How can I retrieve list of Active Directory users

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I am working on an intranet ASP.NET MVC web application, and I need to retrieve all the user names from Active Directory (I do not need groups).

Currently I have enabled Windows authentication and users can sign in directly to the web application. And for the data access layer I am using Entity Framework.

But I need to get all the user names for administration purposes, and assign these users to my application custom groups which I have created. Any idea about how to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
   // and with the first name (GivenName) of "Bruce" 
   UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
   qbeUser.GivenName = "Bruce";

   // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
   PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

   // find all matches
   foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
   {
       // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
   }
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.

Of course, depending on your need, you might want to specify other properties on that "query-by-example" user principal you create:

- `DisplayName` (typically: first name + space + last name)
- `SAM Account Name` - your Windows/AD account name
- `User Principal Name` - your "username@yourcompany.com" style name

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.

Comment: thanks for the reply i created a new class inside the model folder. But i am getting the following erros that the PrincipalContext & ContextType.Domain can not be found.

Comment: @johnG: you need to add a reference to `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` to your project